# Cómo comparar porciones de Strings dentro de una lista

Tags: java, string, lista, bucles, comparaciones

esta es mi primera consulta en la plataforma. Estoy programando en JAVA.

Necesito que, dado un mazo de 5 cartas de póquer representadas cada una con un String (Ej: "10D" = 10 de Diamantes, "AC", "2P", etc.) pasados por parámetro, pueda retornar true (hay póquer) si 4 de esas 5 cartas contienen el mismo valor.
Lo que hice fue meter esas cadenas en un Array para poder iterarlas en un bucle *for*. Entonces, dada la carta **a** y la carta **b** se comparan los primeros caracteres si estás cadenas tienen la misma longitud. Esta comparación la hago con **regionMatches**. Si se da un Match sumo 1 en un contador inicializado en 1 porque asumo que la primera carta ya contiene el valor a comparar.

Esta solución no funciona porque lo que hace es comparar linealmente. Y si la segunda carta no tiene la misma longitud que la primera, no la saltea y compara la primera con la tercera, sino que compara la segunda con la tercera. No sé como implementar eso sin pensar en anidaciones de *if*.

Discúlpenme si no pude expresar bien mi duda, pero la verdad es que estoy un poco enredado. Les agradecería mucho si me dan una mano. Les dejo el código que implementé:

```
public class PoquerStatus {

public boolean verificar(String cartaUno, String cartaDos, String cartaTres, String cartaCuatro,
        String cartaCinco) {
    List<String> cartas = new ArrayList<String>();
    cartas.add(cartaUno);
    cartas.add(cartaDos);
    cartas.add(cartaTres);
    cartas.add(cartaCuatro);
    cartas.add(cartaCinco);
    
    return chequearPoker(cartas);
}

public boolean chequearPoker(List<String> cartas) {
    // asumimos que la primera carta es el valor que vamos a comparar, así que el contador comienza en 1
    int sum = 1;
    // pongo un 4 en lugar de "cartas.size() -1", ya que sabemos que el arreglo de cartas siempre será de 5 elementos, y para asegurar el caso borde resto 1
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        String a = cartas.get(i);
        String b = cartas.get(i+1);
        sum = sum + compararRegionYSumar(a, b);
    }
    String a = cartas.get(0);
    String b = cartas.get(4);
    sum = sum + compararRegionYSumar(a, b);
    
    return sum == 4;
}

public int compararRegionYSumar(String a, String b ) {
    if (a.regionMatches(0, b, 0, b.length() -1)) {
        return 1;
    }
    else { return 0; }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Hola, quizas te convenga abordar este problema de una forma mas orientada a objetos. Considera crear una clase que se llame `Carta` por ejemplo, que tenga ciertos métodos que te faciliten la comparación de valores. Podrías tener un método en `Carta` como carta1.mismoValor(carta2) que te diga si tienen el mismo valor sin importar si tienen la misma pinta (diamante, corazon, etc).

Comment: Entiendo! eso mismo tengo que hacer en un ejercicio más adelante. Pero en este requerimiento solicitan que sí o sí el chequeo sea con cartas representadas con un String tipo "QC" (Reina de Corazones).
Una alternativa que se me ocurre es tomar los primeros caracteres que representan el valor, para formar subcadenas y comprarlas una por una en distintos casos de matcheo. Por ejemplo: cartaUno.equals(cartaDos) && cartaUno.equals(cartaTres), etc. Pero no sé si sea una solución "linda".

Comment: Ah bien, es por requerimiento lo de los strings, entiendo. Me surge la duda de si cuando dices: `si 4 de esas 5 cartas contienen el mismo valor.` Con mismo valor te refieres a que sean el mismo string? Ej: carta1 = "1C" y carta2 = "1C", es decir tienes dos "1 de corazones". O con "mismo valor" te refieres a la parte "numérica" (tambien las letras de las cartas de poker) Ej: carta1 = "2D" y carta2 = "2C" <- esto se tomaría como mismo valor tambien?

Comment: Claro! el valor va del 1 al 10 y J, Q, K. Eso por un lado. Y por el otro tenemos los palos C = Corazones, T, P, D... estos palos los obvio con el `regionMatches`. Aunque también se me ocurre utilizar `replaceFirst` para quitar ese último carácter que representa al palo, así solo me quedo con el valor. Pero el inconveniente está en la lógica para comparar esos valores y retornarme si hay o no póquer